# How to display an array into list and return it?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => red
       [1] => blue 
       [2] => yellow 
       [3] => black 
       [4] => white )
```

So my question is how to I display the value into this :

```
<li>red</li>
<li>blue</li>
<li>yellow</li>
<li>black</li>
<li>white</li>
```

I want the list to become the return value in a function.

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, this isn't basic PHP, this is basic *programming*. You need to do one of the most fundamental things that one can do with an array.

Comment: Please, read the API: http://php.net/

Comment: sorry guys, my mind went blank for a moment just now. I figured it out just right after I submit this question. Actually what I trying to ask is not about listing the array, I want the list to be able become the return value in a function. But its not a problem now, because I already solved it. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way:

```
echo '<li>' . join('</li><li>', $array) . '</li>';
```

If `newline` is necessary, then

```
 echo '<li>' . join("</li><li>\n", $array) . '</li>';
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `implode()` instead of the alias? P.S. you forgot the linefeeds.

Comment: @Petra Yep, `join()` is the alias of `implode()`, nothing wrong to use a alias.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial way.

```
function foo($array) {
    $output = '';
    foreach($array as $element) {
        $output .= '<li>'.$element.'</li>';
    }   
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: three concatenation, and a variable more than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $array = array('red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'white');

    foreach($array as $value) {
        echo "<li>$value</li>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Manual foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

This is the link you'll need, and an example as to how you would do this:

```
<?php
$myarray = array('red','blue','yellow','black','white');

foreach($myarray as $key=>$val)
{
    print('<li>' . $val . '</li>'); 
}
?>
```

Or if you would prefer to print your HTML outside of PHP (like i do) you could do it like this:

```
<?php
$myarray = array('red','blue','yellow','black','white');

foreach($myarray as $key=>$val)
{
    ?>
    <li><?=$val?></li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr= ( 
       '0' => 'red'
       '1' => 'blue' 
       '2' => 'yellow' 
       '3' => 'black' 
       '4' => 'white' );
$list_html= li_function($arr);

function li_function($arr)
{
  foreach($arr as $key=>$values)
  {
      $str .= '<li>'.$values.'</li>';
  }
  return $str;
}
```

You can find more at http://www.phpsyntax.blogspot.in

Answer (score 0):

You should normally make the function return the array.

In your *template* you then can make use of it. If you do not use a templating system yet, consider a lightweight one like Mustache. Or use plain PHP:

```
<?php foreach($array as $value) { ?>
    <li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($value); ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

That will allow you to change the output later on while you do not need to change all your functions.